# Fragment view memory leak despite setting parent view to null in onDestroyView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I know that adding a fragment transaction to the `backstack` and then moving from that fragment to another fragment, the `reference of the previous fragment's view is still available` and it only gets destroyed when the back button is pressed. 
And to avoid this, `I have set the view to null in onDestroyView` but the problem is, `leakcanary still shows view is not null and the view reference is still available` whereas logging the view says it is null.

Why is it so ? 
Also, please correct me if I'm wrong or missing anything.

**The fragment class-**

```kotlin
private var mView: View? = null
private lateinit var btnSignUp: Button

 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)
        return mView
    }

 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        btnSignUp = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp)

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener {
            // calling function changeFragment()
            changeFragment(SignUpFragment(), FragmentsTag.SIGNUP_FRAGMENT)
        }
    }

override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()      
         mView=null
    }
```

**LeakCanary Analysis logs** --

```
  HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
    ====================================
    1 APPLICATION LEAKS

    References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
    Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.

    43817 bytes retained by leaking objects
    Signature: 6e77557c8a679dd41391c1c5badaac98217366ad
    ┬───
    │ GC Root: System class
    │
    ├─ leakcanary.internal.InternalLeakCanary class
    │    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
    │    ↓ static InternalLeakCanary.resumedActivity
    ├─ com.example.foodrunner.activities.MainActivity instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is false)
    │    ↓ MainActivity.mFragments
    ├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ FragmentController.mHost
    ├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.mFragmentManager
    ├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ FragmentManagerImpl.mActive
    ├─ java.util.HashMap instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ HashMap.table
    ├─ java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry[] array
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ HashMap$HashMapEntry[].[0]
    ├─ java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ HashMap$HashMapEntry.value
    ├─ com.example.foodrunner.fragments.LoginFragment instance
    │    Leaking: NO (Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
    │    Fragment.mTag=Login Fragment
    │    ↓ LoginFragment.btnLogin
    │                    ~~~~~~~~
    ├─ com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton instance
    │    Leaking: YES (View detached and has parent)
    │    mContext instance of com.example.foodrunner.activities.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    View#mParent is set
    │    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    │    View.mID = R.id.btnLogin
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    │    ↓ MaterialButton.mParent
    ╰→ androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout instance
    ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.foodrunner.fragments.LoginFragment received Fragment#onDestroyView() callback (references to its views should be cleared to prevent leaks))
    ​     key = b72a82a6-b9dd-46c6-afb2-0ea6c7025001
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 9582
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 4582
    ​     key = 0554b63a-c700-4c86-a451-b0daae06607a
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 9581
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 4580
    ​     mContext instance of com.example.foodrunner.activities.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
    ​     View#mParent is null
    ​     View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    ​     View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    ====================================
```

Comment: try setting all it's UI components to null in onDestroyView, It might solve your issue.

Comment: Do I have to set all views to null? Won't setting the parent view to null work??

Comment: Ideally it should. If it doesn't work, and it is a big UI you can run a loop to set all view to null.

Comment: Yeah it works but using loop for setting views to null might not be the accurate way

Comment: It would be as if you are setting every individual view.

Comment: Remove it from the fragment manager which is handling the fragment transactions

Comment: Setting parent view to null works ??

Comment: @KaranKhurana setting both the ```parent view``` and the ```btn```  to null did not show any memory leak. Means all the class variables has to be set null in ```onDestroyView```

Comment: @Rafsanjani Can you provide some code for doing so??

Comment: @KaranKhurana another thing that worked is, in ```onDestroyView``` getting the view and calling ```removeAllView``` on the view. That is,                                                  ```(view as ViewGroup).removeAllViews()```  It didnot require setting any other view to null. But I dont think it is the appropriate way.

Comment: yes I have tried it too, but it can behave abruptly at times

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're still holding onto a reference to `btnSignUp` after `onDestroyView` - **that** is what is leaking. You have to drop **all** reference to **all** Views within the view that was just destroyed.

Therefore you should either use the same approach (make it a nullable `var`) or not hold onto a reference to `btnSignUp` in your Fragment at all - at least in your code sample, it could easily be a local variable. (In fact, the same applies to your `mView` - you get the `View` as an input to `onViewCreated()`, there's no reason to hold onto it at the Fragment level).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pointing to my mistake. It's working perfect now. Not showing any leaks.

Answer (score 0):

As *@Rafsanjani* mention you can use this too :

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
trans.remove(myFrag);
trans.commit();
manager.popBackStack();
```

*Use this in your onBackPressed*